# Access current row data in Vuestic UI Data Table from template

Tags: vuejs3, vuestic

due to lack of migration to Vue3 from Vuetify, I turned to Vuestic UI, which seems to do the job as intented, without to much of a pain to switch.

I have to display data, in a Data Table component, coming from an external API. Got it all working.
I'm using slots to control displayed data, but I'm missing a functionality which was implemented in Vuetify.

I have to access the current row's data in a cell to format an email address, but I can't get it to work.

Basically, i would like to get something as this code portion in Vuetify:

```
<v-data-table >
   <template v-slot:item.colName="{ item }">
     // Do something with the current item data
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```

I came up with this code from the official documentation

```
<va-data-table>
    <template #cell(email.0.value)="{ value }">
        <a :href="`mailto:${value}?subject=${getRowDataHere}`">
            {{ value }}
        </a>
    </template>
</va-data-table>
```

I don't know if I a missing something here, but I've been searching around since yersterday without any positive results.

EDIT: After diving in the Vuestic github Repo, and going through the main code, here is the solution for some in need :

```
<template #cell(colKey)="{ rowData }">
   {{ rowData.property }}
</template>
```

Comment: Table cell slot attributes that can be accessed - [source code](https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-ui/blob/c8d0a30fcbcebe66ba16c7e442732b977737af41/packages/ui/src/components/va-data-table/hooks/useRows.ts#L34)